# Access previous versions of form definitions with Orbeon

Tags: orbeon, xforms

It appears that Orbeon does not support form versioning. When a change is made to a form definition, the form builder will only show the most recent version of the form. We are using MySql to store our data and I have noticed that the form definition is not overwritten in the database. A new line is added with a newer time stamp.

One requirement we have is that old revisions of a form must be trackable. At the very least we need to be able to view old versions of a form. How can this be done? The only way I can think of doing this is creating an instance of a form named with the revision everytime the form definition is updated. Has anyone found a better way to handle versioning in Orbeon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, and this includes the upcoming Orbeon Forms 4.0, there is no proper form versioning feature in Orbeon Forms (but we have [some ideas as to how to implement this](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/projects/form-runner-builder/form-builder-versioning)).

If what you want is that form data entered with a given version of a form definition is always loaded with that same version of the form definition, then unfortunately that feature isn't there.

Now, as you have noticed when using MySQL or Oracle, form data and form definitions are never actually deleted from the database. But this is more of an auditing feature rather than a versioning feature. With this, if you just want to find or restore an older version of a form, you can do this with a SQL query.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm a little uncertain on how to use the XML data in the database. So if I do grab the XML data for a form template with a SQL query, how would I open it in the form builder/runner?

Comment: If you update that form definition's `last_modified` in the `orbeon_form_definition ` table to be "now", that will make that version of the form definition the one retrieved by Form Runner. That's the only way Form Runner will find it. It can only find the latest form definition.